# Out of memory error: Java heap memory on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do I fix `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when compiling my Android project?

I get this after I upgraded to version 1 of Android Studio. But, I don't think this is the problem. Most likely when I start upgrading my app to SDK 21 (before this was SDK 20). But I wasn't so sure either.

I've googled around for [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap) [fix](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html), but couldn't find one that works. Most of the fix are for Eclipse IDE.

This is the full logcat error that I get when compiling:

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(net.lingala.zip4j.zip.ZipEngine$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec$ForComparison.toRegisterSpec(RegisterSpec.java:642)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec.intern(RegisterSpec.java:73)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec.make(RegisterSpec.java:90)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:323)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitLocal(Simulator.java:612)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:412)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:94)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:787)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:742)
    at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:332)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:243)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\sdfasd\android-sdks\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list C:\Users\asdfasdf\workspace\Baucar\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt --output C:\Users\asdfasdf\workspace\Baucar\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\asdfasdf\workspace\Baucar\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    3
Output:
    warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
    (net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip$1) that doesn't come with an
    associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
    compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
    solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
    and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
    this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
    indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
    warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
    (net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip$2) that doesn't come with an
    associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
    compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
    solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
    and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
    this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
    indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
    warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
    (net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer$1) that doesn't come with an
    associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
    compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
    solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
    and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
    this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
    indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
    warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
    (net.lingala.zip4j.util.ArchiveMaintainer$2) that doesn't come with an
    associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
    compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
    solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
    and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
    this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
    indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
    warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
    (net.lingala.zip4j.zip.ZipEngine$1) that doesn't come with an
    associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
    compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
    solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
    and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
    this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
    indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
    
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec$ForComparison.toRegisterSpec(RegisterSpec.java:642)
        at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec.intern(RegisterSpec.java:73)
        at com.android.dx.rop.code.RegisterSpec.make(RegisterSpec.java:90)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.RopperMachine.run(RopperMachine.java:323)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator$SimVisitor.visitLocal(Simulator.java:612)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.BytecodeArray.parseInstruction(BytecodeArray.java:412)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Simulator.simulate(Simulator.java:94)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:787)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:742)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:332)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:243)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Is it because of one jar library I used (zip4j)? I did try to remove it, but the OOM error still occurs. Any idea how to fix this?

---

**Edit:**

I've also edited gradlew file to increase the -Xmx size.

```
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\" \"-Xmx2048M \"-XX:MaxPermSize=512M\" \"-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512M\""
```

Nothing changes.

---

**Edit 2:**

Also did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23441908/996701) fix but couldn't help it too:

Try the following:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> -> Compiler -> Gradle

In`VM Options` field write:

```
-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: Check heap dump ...you also can add  android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: @Prachi nothing helps. I can't even compile and run it, how am I suppose to check the heap dump?

Comment: Edited. Added a fix I did in gradlew file.

Comment: I have tried this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429299/10288513) and it worked for me.

Comment: If anyone comes across this problem and is on AS 3.5+ on Mac, you can try [this GitHub](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8139#issuecomment-543050424) solution. Among the ocean of different answers here on SO, this was what worked for me (and many others by comment's the reactions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've finally solved it by limiting the Google Play service in gradle dependency.

The problem however was caused by the Google Play service, and by simply change it to a specific library, it is now solved.

```
 com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87
```

**UPDATE**

More info on [android guides](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Answer (score 89):

**Update 2022;** DSL element **'`dexOptions`' is obsolete** and should be removed.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
**Using it has no effect**, and the AndroidGradle plugin optimizes dexing automatically.

I tested and with Gradle `7.0+`, increasing below mentioned `org.gradle.jvmargs` option is all we need.

### Original Answer

I had a similar issue on Android Studio 2.3.3. APK packaging would fail saying `Java heap space` when building from Android Studio and trying to process a 300MB .so library. In my case two things were needed to fix it. Your `build.gradle` should contain something like that:

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
    }
}
```

At the root of your project you need to have a file named `gradle.properties` containing the following:

```
# That's needed for java to be able the create the APK with our 300MB native  library
# Basically we grant java a 4GB heap.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Comment: it's important not to miss the second part of the answer ;)

Comment: This helped me with gradle 8.1.2, thanks, so perhaps it still has some affect, or it was just pot luck.

Answer (score 34):

This is old, but just add this to the build file

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
```

Comment: Graeme thanks! Parameters in 'gradle.properties' were for unknown reason always ignored. This helped perfectly!

Comment: If using *dx* from the command line, you need to pass the flag *-JXmx2g*: `dx -JXmx2g --dex ...`

Comment: Modified to "4g" and the outofmemory error happens from time to time.

Comment: Warning: DSL element 'dexOptions' is obsolete and should be removed.

Answer (score 20):

> Build => Clean Project

then

> Build => Rebuild Project

When I do this, it always fixes for me.

Comment: I see this advice in a lot of issues and it's true that a rebuild can fix most of them. What bothers me is why we have to clean first? Isn't rebuild automatically do a clean?

Comment: Actually `Rebuild Project` contains `Clean Project`. So it doesn't need to `Clean Project`, if you are going to `Rebuild Project`.

Answer (score 18):

You can do this with the UI in Android Studio, [with friendly defaults](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Android%20Studio%20has,Gradle%20daemon%2C%20and%20Kotlin%20daemon.)

[image: Click File > Settings from the menu bar (or Android Studio > Preferences on macOS). Click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Memory Settings.]

Comment: To put it more nicely than the previous comments did: This answer would be *better* if it also described in text, in the answer, exactly what to do.  Linked pages can change, as this one has: it no longer jumps to the highlighted text you included in the link.  All a screen reader user can see here is "enter image description here".

Comment: note, global settings will be overriden by properties.gradle, and just commenting the line will not help. I had have to set Xmx2048 despite on global memory setting 4096

Comment: this work! 
up vote this to becaome real answer

Answer (score 13):

Open gradle.properties files in the root of you project

Add this line:

```
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Just remove `#` in front of the line.

Answer (score 8):

assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.For example:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m

Comment: Just to reiterate, this needs to go in the `gradle.properties` file, not `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 8):

Change the following line in `properties.gradle` to a higher number as shown below

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1132m
```

to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

Comment: gradle.properties?

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I did:

1st step: In your App, go to GRADLE SCRIPTS -> GRADLE.PROPERTIES -> change *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmxm* to *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G*

2nd Step: In your App, go to GRADLE SCRIPTS -> build.gradle -> in the 
android{

//add this line:

```
dexOptions {
   javaMaxHeapSize = "4G"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i'm using Windows OS. I solved this by updating _JAVA_OPTIONS to '-Xmx1024m'

1. Win + X, choose SYSTEM
2. Choose 'Advanced system settings'
3. Choose 'Environment Variables'
4. Create / Edit a variable named as '_JAVA_OPTIONS'
5. update variable value as -Xmx1024m

[click to see snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5jJx.png)

Comment: Solved my problem. bundletool was reporting memory errors +1.

Answer (score 3):

You have changed the wrong arguments, you should increase the size on `-XX:MaxPermSize=512M` to `-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M` or so :) because the android emulator uses a lot of RAM.

Comment: Same error :( Should I add more memory to the maxperm?

Comment: yes, do that and see what happens :)
BTW: how much RAM do you have on your machine?

Comment: This is not correct, XX:MaxPermSize is used to store "data needed by the virtual machine to describe objects that do not have an equivalence at the Java language level. For example objects describing classes and methods are stored in the permanent generation." (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) I can hardly think of any scenario where AimanB's code and Android Studio would require more than 512MB of RAM to store Classes (*not* Objects) and Methods. The problem lie elsewhere

Comment: You have a point there. Maybe the best thing now would be to create a dump with jvisualVM (it's in the bin folder of your jdk) and then analyze it with MAT, which is free and better for analyzing dumps.

Comment: start the jvisualVM before you start the emulator, and you can see in the left side of jvisualVM's window the active processes, start then the emulator, you will see in JVM the emulator's process and open the monitor tab, you will see how much heap will allocate for the process. After your java android process crashes create a dump with JVM and then open that dump with MAT and investigate all the leaks.

Answer (score 3):

The answers above are for gradle builds (or the general -Xmx). In case someone gets here for a non-gradle project, I solved the issue by increasing the maximum heap size of DEX in android studio settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Compiler => Android Compilers

Comment: I found this config in File - > other Settings -> Default Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Android Compilers

Answer (score 2):

I have faced to the same problem after lots of research I found this solution.
you can solve this problem by changing this. go to `gradle.properties` and change

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx500m
```

to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me but finally I found something that worked in my case:

**Automatically managing paging files size**

In windows:

1. Under "Advanced System Settings"
2. Advanced Tab
3. Performance section, settings...
4. Advanced Tab
5. Virtual memory... Change...
6. Select **Automatically manage paging files size for all drives**

I don't remember why I had this unchecked but this was causing trouble in my gradle builds (with flutter).

Answer (score 1):

Close emulator and then build. Default doesn't allow both at once for me

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your **gradle.properties** file, to avoid this bug.

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:+UseParallelGC -Xmx2048M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx4608m" -XX\:MaxPermSize\=1024m -XX\:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
#avoid check for debug
gradle=build -x lint -x lintVitalRelease
#decreases the startup & execution time
org.gradle.deamon=true
#build project in parallel (milti-module)
org.gradle.parallel=true
#store task outputs from previous builds
org.gradle.caching=true
#only required projects changes
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

But carefully study each line.

Answer (score 1):

The OOM happened to me after I edit a few lines of code in my project. The android studio freeze with some `indexing...` message.

I tried to force kill the app & restart as usually but not affect.

So I set:

- in `gradle.properties` -> `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=4g`
- in `/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/studio.vmoptions` -> `-Xmx8g`

and still nothing.

The UI was totally freeze & I couldn't do `File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart`
Also, I tried to delete `.gradle/caches` but no affect.

To my luck, I had 2 versions of Android Studio: Arctic Fox & 4.2.

Android Studio 4.2 is the one that was totally freeze.

My hint was to:

- open & rebuild the project with Android Studio Arctic Fix
- open the project with Android Studio 4.2

I know there are hundreds of different suggested options, but nothing was helpful to me. So, decided to share my hint.

Hope, this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also may happen with usage of the debug build of Proguard. To solve it change `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to false.

```
android {
...
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
} }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add this to the gradle file:

```
android{
testOptions {
        ....
        unitTests.all {
            jvmArgs "-Xmx2g" // to avoid outOfMemory exception
        }
        ....
    }
}
```