# Facebook SDK compilation error

Tags: android, facebook, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to compile my project with Facebook SDK, sdk v4.8.2, but i have tried earliest versions. Here is my Gradle Build messages:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: Cannot merge new index 66457 into a non-jumbo instruction!
at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.jumboCheck(InstructionTransformer.java:111)
at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.access$800(InstructionTransformer.java:26)
at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer$StringVisitor.visit(InstructionTransformer.java:74)
at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.callVisit(CodeReader.java:114)
at com.android.dx.io.CodeReader.visitAll(CodeReader.java:89)
at com.android.dx.merge.InstructionTransformer.transform(InstructionTransformer.java:50)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformCode(DexMerger.java:826)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformMethods(DexMerger.java:800)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassData(DexMerger.java:773)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.transformClassDef(DexMerger.java:669)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:523)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':hotelClient:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 8.023 secs
Information:1 error
```

This project was have an old facebook library, integrated as project dependency. But old one files already deleted.

**UPDATE**

with multidex

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of   ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Uncaught translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':hotelClient:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem of multidex file so please add below dependency to your app Gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Also add this line:

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId 'pkg'
    minSdkVersion 
    targetSdkVersion 
    versionCode 
    versionName 

    // Enable MultiDexing:  https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Edited :

Also add below in `Manifest.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks..!!

Comment: @ Drake : Also try this out -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438145/out-of-memory-error-java-heap-memory-on-android-studio