# Android Studio error "Java heap space"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, heap-memory

I'm developing an Android app in Android Studio and today suddenly it doesn't compile when I press the "Run" button. The error is this:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.
>   Java heap space

I've tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it but it didn't work.

Comment: looks like you ran out of memory, can you check the ram usage of your pc, or the java max ram settings?

Comment: This might help you [How to fix Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645747/android-studio-gradle-build-failing-java-heap-space)

Comment: I already tried adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m` to my gradle.properties but it didn't work

Comment: Ram usage on my PC is at 50% so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: `256m` is probably lower than what you started with. Set it higher, such as `1024m`. "Ram usage on my PC is at 50% so I don't think that's the problem" -- that means nothing in this case.

Comment: Not working, I tried even with 2048

Comment: Possible duplicate see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547100/error-in-build-gradle-in-android-studio for more solutions

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions but finally, this helped me to solve this problem : -

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

use this line in your "gradle-wrapper.properties". hope it helps others too.