# How do I fix this error? java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)

Tags: android, android-studio

Error while building apk.Who is getting this error.How can I fix this error?

```
 Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
       > java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: what do you mean by "When I run android"? Do you mean you're launching Android Studio?

Comment: Error while building apk

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67674074/188331)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try
`android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest.xml also check if you are loading an image with large size directly into xml imageView using `src` or `app:srcCompat` if that you can use library like Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

you should check if there is an open packager in the background, if yes, so close it and try to run again