# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message) - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

[image]

So I'm getting this particular error for a while when I'm trying to run a react native app, I actually kinda know what it is. This error shows up when the emulator doesnt have enough storage to install the app (at least I think this way). So I wiped the data in emulator from android studio. But it didn't work. Then I created new emulator with 32 GB. Got error again, and this is what I saw after I tried to run the app;

[image]

I feel like something is filling up all the space no matter how big it is. Not sure what is wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error)

Comment: @Joel no it does not

Comment: You've tried all the answers there? 

Comment: it's not the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70090508/how-do-i-fix-this-error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-no-error-message

Comment: How much memory do you have on the machine where you are building the app?

Comment: This bug isn't about storage on the emulator (which could easily be fixed by increasing it).  This is RAM on your PC when running the packageDebug command.  You need to give gradle more RAM in order to perform the action.  (Gradle is the build system used for Android apps)