# There is not enough memory to perform requested operation-Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm

I have been using Android Studio 2.1 for a while now, and in my previous projects, it seemed to work just fine. But now I got this error:
[image]

This pestered me for a while until I decided to google solutions and ended up with some informative details like [how to increase the heapsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size) and [this seemed to work for the OP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440647/android-studio-gradle-outofmemory-error)

I haven't been successful yet.

I have twerked with the `studio64.vmoptions` file directly (even though A.S explicitly adviced otherwise, but i was desperate)

I noticed the problem occured  a while later after intergrating Google Places API  but i cannot establish the connection yet between the two.

Any suggestions? I could really use some help, my backlogged work is pilling up :(

This is how my vmoptions looks like:

```js
# custom Android Studio VM options

#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

Just additional info: I am on a Linux OS.

Comment: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861943/any-solution-for-android-studio-slow-gradle-build-and-high-disk-usage/36862637#36862637) and see if it helps

Comment: i have checked it out, implemented your suggestions, now im waitig to see how it works out.

Comment: Something to note though, i have a ram of  5788 and about  1511 free. I had allocated Xms512m -Xmx2048m, and yur suggestions, advices lower. What are your thoughts? Isn,t the higher the values, the higher the performance?

Comment: well it doesn't the case always because studio doesn't use this much of ram always, and those settings a perfect fit and working so fine for me for all versions, just try them out if they works for you too that is why i included them as a comment not a answer :)

Comment: I really appreciate how informative your answer is on the link. Let me give it a couple of mnutes and see how it works out.

Comment: Well nothing has happened yet which means that it's working efficiently! Let me upvote your answer o the link, really helpful!

Comment: thanks man, Glad I could help :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size

Answer (score 9):

You can improve **Gradle performance** to avoid this message.

Create a file named gradle.properties in

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

and add the line:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

This helps a lot, with `org.gradle.daemon` set to true `Gradle` reuses computations from previous builds and cache information about project structure, files, tasks etc. in memory so it won’t have to start up the entire `Gradle` application every time.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using Ubuntu 20.04, with 16GB of RAM which was mostly available, so this problem is clearly caused by something else other than lack of memory.

I solved it by closing the project and deleting the `build` and `app/build` directories within the project I was working on.
On the next open I was able to code and build the app normally.

Comment: Interesting. I have never experienced this again ever since, moved to Mac.

Comment: This issue is occurring for me now on a mac :D Also, there weren't even any build or app/build folders yet. So weird.

Comment: This is not working to me :(( I have deleted the build folder on both projectDir/build and projectDir/app/build.

Comment: I faced it after introducing hilt to my project and accidentally tried injecting a field in an inner class. Resolved it by removing the build folders.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error while opening project.
Below solution works for me.

Close Android Studio

Remove **caches** folder from **`C:\Users\USER_NAME\.AndroidStudio3.4\system`**

Reopen Android Studio and open or import project

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue and i solved the problem by expanding emulator storage and sd card space[image: emulator options]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating Android Studio to the latest version.

[image]